# MySQL not using index when where condition have if clause

Tags: mysql, indexing

Below is the query

```
SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE if(@type=1,col1,col2) = 1420070400;
```

`@type` is a session variable.

I have two `indexes` defined on both columns `col1` and `col2` but mysql does not uses in this case. Is there any way by which we can make mysql use `index`?

Below is explain result

```
mysql> explain extended SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE if(@type=1,col1,col2) = 1420070400;
+----+-------------+-----------------+------+---------------+------+---------+------+------+----------+-------------+
| id | select_type | table           | type | possible_keys | key  | key_len | ref  | rows | filtered | Extra       |
+----+-------------+-----------------+------+---------------+------+---------+------+------+----------+-------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | mytable         | ALL  | NULL          | NULL | NULL    | NULL | 1523 |   100.00 | Using where |
+----+-------------+-----------------+------+---------------+------+---------+------+------+----------+-------------+
```

Comment: What does `explain select ...` says for the above query ? Add that into the question.

Answer (score 2):

In general, databases (including MySQL) do not use indexes when columns are the arguments to functions.

You could try:

```
SELECT *
FROM mytable
WHERE (@type = 1 and col1 = 1420070400) or
      (@type <> 1 and col2 = 1420070400);
```

But, it is unlikely that this will use an index either.  You can phrase the query like this:

```
SELECT *
FROM mytable
WHERE @type = 1 and col1 = 1420070400
UNION ALL
SELECT *
FROM mytable
WHERE @type <> 1 and col2 = 1420070400
```

A `UNION ALL` is fine, because only one of the subqueries should actually run.  This version should make use of two separate indexes, one on `mytable(col1)` and the other on `mytable(col2)`.  Note:  a single composite index is not sufficient.